# How would one find the total cases by manager

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, recursive-query

I have two tables: one that has cases alongside the employees who resolve them and one that has information on the employees including their managers. I want to make a query that finds the amount of cases under each manager. Currently my query looks like this

```
select m.id, COUNT(distinct case when e.manager_id = m.id and a.resolver_id = e.id then a.ticket_id ELSE NULL END)
from tickets a 
left join employee_info e on a.resolver_id= e.id
join employee_info m on e.manager_id = m.id
group by m.id
```

This query only gave me the count of the direct employees under a manager, not the count of all employees (including the ones under the people reporting directly to the manager). How would I tweak my query to include all employees under a person?

***EDIT***

So this is an obfuscated example of how my tables look

```
Ticket_id resolver_id
0001      11
0002      11
0003      13
0004      13
0005      12
0006      19
```

```
Id manager_id
11 01
12 01
13 11
19 12
```

and this is how I want my result to look

```
Id count
01 6
11 4
12 2
13 2
19 1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results (as tabular text) to clarify your requirement.

Comment: @GMB I have edited my post with sample data and desired results

Comment: Not enough records to verify the desired count.

Comment: @June7 what do you mean by that?

Comment: There are only 6 ticket records but total count is 15. How do you derive that? Also 01 is not in ID field so why is it in ID output? Just read question again. You want ALL people under manager down the chain? Sounds like recursive logic - which is beyond me.

Comment: @June7 The total count isnt 15. I want to find the total tickets (including subordinates) for each person. So 01 is the manager of all the resolver_ids, so the tickets are all under him. 11 is the manager of 13, so his count includes the 2 he did himself and the 2 done by 13. I believe this is recursive logic

Comment: If you add all the Count values you get 15 but I suppose records are counted more than once. As I said recursive logic is beyond me. Access doesn't handle this well, definitely not in query, and I would have to use a VBA solution. Other dbs such as SQLServer are supposed to handle this. I have seen many discussions. Don't know if any will address your exact data but suggest you do a web search on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have a "tree" of employees, and want to recursively traverse it. This is what recursive CTEs are for.

We'll define a "subordinate" cte, that will tell us all the "subordinate relationships" between all employees, including "multi-level" subordination. If A is manager of B, and B is manager of C, then A has as subordinates B and C.

First, we start with all employees being their own subordinates. This is the non-recursive part.

```sql
    SELECT id AS id1, id AS id2
    FROM employee
```

Then, we "expand one level down" the subordinate relationships.  if B is subordinate of A, all employees with B as manager are also subordinates of A. id1 stys as-is, id2 becomes the id of the "lower" employee. This is the recursive part.

```sql
    SELECT s.id1, e.id
    FROM subordinate s
    JOIN employee e ON s.id2 = e.manager_id
```

Then we stick both in a recursive CTE. Postgres will iterate the 2nd part as many times as needed, until no new rows are added. This way we recusrively traverse the entire employee tree.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE subordinate AS (
    SELECT id AS id1, id AS id2
    FROM employee
UNION
    SELECT s.id1, e.id
    FROM subordinate s
    JOIN employee e ON s.id2 = e.manager_id
)
select * from subordinate order by id1, id2;
```

Let's check the result:

```
 id1 | id2 
-----+-----
   1 |   1
   1 |  11
   1 |  12
   1 |  13
   1 |  19
  11 |  11
  11 |  13
  12 |  12
  12 |  19
  13 |  13
  19 |  19
```

Looking great! 1 has everyone as subordinates. 11 has 11 and 13, and lowst employees such as 13 and 19 only have themselves.

Once we have done this, the rest is easy.

We can do another CTE counting the resolved tickets per employee:

```sql
    SELECT resolver_id as id, COUNT(*) as count
    FROM tickets
    GROUP BY resolver_id
```

and then we stick everything into the final query. For every employee, sum the resolved count of all its subordinates.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE subordinate AS (
    SELECT id AS id1, id AS id2
    FROM employee
UNION
    SELECT s.id1, e.id
    FROM subordinate s
    JOIN employee e ON s.id2 = e.manager_id
),
resolved as (
    SELECT resolver_id as id, COUNT(*) as count
    FROM tickets
    GROUP BY resolver_id
)
SELECT s.id1, SUM(r.count)
FROM subordinate s
JOIN resolved r ON r.id = s.id2
GROUP BY s.id1;
```